# $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name return null value after converting ps1 to exe

Tags: powershell

powershell script results in incorrect output after converting it to an .exe-file and executing it:

```
$MyScriptName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
```

Above is snippet of my powershell code, which works fine and saves the script name in the `$MyScriptName` variable.

Once we convert the .ps1-script to an .exe-file and execute it, the variable `$MyScriptName` has a null value.

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with C#, Python, POSIX shells, or Perl?

Comment: How gets the script converted?

Comment: Try [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.FriendlyName

Comment: is there some reason you would expect that automatic variable to be filled in when you have removed the process that provides the data it uses? [*grin*] my understanding is that the info is generated _when the powershell host loads the script_ ... and that aint happening when you "convert the script to an exe" ...

Comment: @molbdnilo : Not sure why powershell is not listed here but in my profile during creation i did added the powershell as well ..... still sorry for that

Comment: @Moerwald : Converted using Win-PS2EXE GUI tool

Answer (score 1):

Script related variables become unavailable after converting the script to an executable file. You can find information about it here on Markus Scholtes' release page on Github for the PS2EXE-GUI version (Win-PS2EXE): [PS2EXE-GUI](https://github.com/MScholtes/TechNet-Gallery/tree/master/PS2EXE-GUI)

Here's the code you need to add to your script.

```
if ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.CommandType -eq "ExternalScript")
{ $ScriptPath = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition }
else
{ $ScriptPath = Split-Path -Parent -Path ([Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[0]) }
```

Comment: Why is it that It seems that `$PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters` returns results where `$PsBoundParameters` might not?